# why IDE show "NPE" warning ? when you use listFiles() method

Tags: java

```
File file = new File("E:\\zhiding\\images\\favicon.ico");
if (file.exists()) {
  File[] files = file.getParentFile().listFiles();
    for (File listFile : files) {
       log.info(listFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

if "favicon.ico" file is exist,execute if block code；
but this code in IDEA,it remind me,files may produce "NPE".
as i know,it cann't produce "NPE"。
I want to know why IEAD show the warning ?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-- — "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Comment: IDEA does not know what `exists()` do, it can not infer that the parent of that file exists, that it is accessible, and, consequently, that `listFiles` *must* return a list

Comment: `listFiles` may return null, even after you've checked that the directory exists, because _absolutely anything_ can happen in another process between the call to `exists()` and the call to `listFiles()`. For example, after you've called `exists()`, someone else may delete the parent directory. Then you call `listFiles()` and it correctly returns null. So IDEA is right to warn you.

Answer (score 0):

`listFiles()` method returns **null** if the path specifies is a file. If the path specified is a directory then it returns a list of files.
I think that is why you see a warning and you may have to carefully operate on the returned object.

Comment: first,thank you for your answer。
your answer give me a direction。now , I know why IDE remind a warning。
when your filepath is a root path，that may produce NPE。
example:

File file = new File("D:\\");

Comment: by me further study. I discover  caused NPE is relation to file authority. if you update the specified file's authority，eg：close the file read authority，then run this code，it caused NPE. I think that.